# Styles not applying to the react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, less

I have a component for a loading message but somehow the styles are not applying to it.

Only the message is appearing on the page not the style.
I tried adding it directly in the js and its working but not when I use the external style sheet. What is going wrong.

.js file :

```
import style from './index.less';

export default class Loading extends Component {

  render() {
        const {
            loading,
            message,
            iconClass,
            textClass,
            containerClass
        } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={containerClass || style.container}>
                <div className={iconClass || style.icon}>
                    <div className={loading ? style.loading : null}/>
                </div>
                <div className={textClass || style.text}>
                    <span>{message}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

less :

```
:local(.index){

  .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
  }

  .icon {
    height: 180px;
    fill: 'Red';
  }

  .text {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.43;
    letter-spacing: 0.6px;
    color: #58585b;
    color: var(--slate-grey);
    text-align: center;
  }

  .loading path:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.1s;
  }

  .loading path:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your file structure. My guess is you need to import style from '../index.less';

Comment: .js and .less files are in the same folder

Comment: I don't work much with Less as with Sass but I don't think importing stylesheet as style [line 1] and then applying as className works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't work much with Less as with Sass but I don't think importing stylesheet as style [line 1] and then applying as className works (at least it doesn't work in Sass).

The **correct way to import styles** would be `import './index.less';`

And then applying as regular classes:

```
return (
        <div className={containerClass ? containerClass : 'container'}>
            <div className={iconClass ? iconClass : 'icon'}>
               ...
);
```

*Also, not sure what `:local(.index){` is supposed to do. I would remove that just to test whether the stylesheet loads properly. Plus, make sure to test with falsy values of containerClass as well as iconClass.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to import it as 
Import './index.less'
and not pass style into props. It will read from your less file based on the given class names in your elements.